# What is `alsoTo` analogue of akka-streams in monix ?

Tags: scala, monix

Monix looks like great framework but documentation is very sparse.

What is `alsoTo` analogue of akka-streams in monix ?

Basically I want stream to be consumed by two consumers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monix follows the Rx model in that subscriptions are dynamic. Any `Observable` supports an unlimited number of subscribers:

```
val obs = Observable.interval(1.second)

val s1 = obs.dump("O1").subscribe()
val s2 = obs.dump("O2").subscribe()
```

There is a catch however — `Observable` is by default what is called a "cold data source", meaning that each subscriber gets its own data source.

So for example, if you had an `Observable` that reads from a `File`, then each subscriber would get its own file handle.

In order to "share" such an `Observable` between multiple subscribers, you have to convert it into a hot data source, to share it. You do so with the `multicast` operator and its versions, `publish` being most commonly used. These give you back a `ConnectableObservable`, that needs a `connect()` call to start the streaming:

```
val shared = obs.publish

// Nothing happens here:
val s1 = shared.dump("O1").subscribe()
val s2 = shared.dump("O2").subscribe()

// Starts actual streaming
val cancelable = shared.connect()

// You can subscribe after connect(), but you might lose events:
val s3 = shared.dump("O3").subscribe()

// You can unsubscribe one of your subscribers, but the
// data source keeps the stream active for the others
s1.cancel()

// To cancel the connection for all subscribers:
cancelable.cancel()
```

PS: [monix.io](https://monix.io) is a work in progress, PRs are welcome